# Трудности с настройками gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, npm, jade, bower

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста, отдебажить свой шаблон для разработки проекта.
Лежит он здесь: https://github.com/sunndeath/Jade-Sass-Gulp-Template

Работать он должен вот так:
1. Имеем папку dev и папку prod
2. При изменении файлов в папке dev - они конкатенируются, минифицируются и отправляются в папку prod, согласно прописанным путям.
js-файлики, например, из папки dev\plugins\install должны отправляться в prod\js\plugins.min.js, при этом, если удаляем что-то из папки dev, то и сам plugins.min.js тоже должен обновиться, согласно изменениям в папке dev.

Возникли трудности с настройками в gulpfile.js

Был бы очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю проблемы с обработкой новых и удаленных файлов. Gulp на них никак не реагирует, т.к. gulp.watch не умеет следить за новыми и удаленными файлами.

Используйте например [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)

Вот так я использую этот плагин в [своем бойлерплейте](https://github.com/zoxon/gulp-front/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L423)